# Searching for chars from a String in a 2d char array?

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array, char

I want to be able to search through my array and find chars that are in a String the user has input? so if the user types "message" I want it to return the index of 'm' 'e' 's' and so on. How would I do this? Heres my code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix {
private char[][] matrix = new char[6][6];
private int[] usedNumbers = new int[50];

{for(int x = 0; x < usedNumbers.length; x++) usedNumbers[x] = -1;}

private final char[] CIPHER_KEY = {'A','D','F','G','V','X'};
private final String validChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";


public Matrix() {
    int random;
    for(int i = 0; i < CIPHER_KEY.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < CIPHER_KEY.length; j++) {
            validation: while(true) {
                random = (int)(Math.random()*validChars.length()-1);
                for(int k = 0; k < usedNumbers.length; k++) {
                    if(random == usedNumbers[k]) continue validation;
                    else if(usedNumbers[k]==-1) usedNumbers[k] = random;
                }
                break;
            }
            matrix[i][j] = validChars.split("")[random].charAt(0);  
        }
    }
}

public void searchMatrix(){

    Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

    String phrase = "";

    System.out.println("\n Enter the message you would like "
            + "to encrypt with the cipher: \n");
    phrase = console.nextLine();

    char[] phraseSplit = phrase.toCharArray();

    console.close();

}

public String toString() {
    String output = "   A D F G V X\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < CIPHER_KEY.length; i++) {
        output += CIPHER_KEY[i] + "  ";
        for(int j = 0; j < CIPHER_KEY.length; j++) {
            output += matrix[i][j] + " ";
        }
        output += "\n";
    }
    return output;
}// toString end

}
```

I have looked for tutorials online but cant find one that would help me in this situation! help? I dont know what to do next.

Comment: There is no need to generate random and then check if number is used already. Just shuffle your char array using `Collections.shuffle()` and take characters one by one from there

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaking, you are almost there. All you have to do is to add nested loops after you got `phraseSplit`.

```
for (int k=0; k<phraseSplit.length; k++) {
    for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {
            if (phraseSplit[k] == matrix[i][j]) {
                System.out.printf("%c at %d, %d\n", phraseSplit[k], i, j);
            }//end if
        }//end for j
    }//end for i
}//end for k
```

There may be better way to do it. Also, Sasha's `shuffle()` is a very good suggestion.